# Connection between Arduino and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io, arduino

I try do achieve a simple thing such as toggling a LED (Arduino) from a web page using an online NodeJS webserver.

There are a lot of topics about this on the web, but most of them either:

- Use the Arduino to serve the web pages
- Use a Serial connection in stead of an internet connection (wifi/ethernet)

In my case, the NodeJS server (using expressJS and optionally SocketIO) will be hosted online and the Arduino should be able to connect from any other network. (ethernet shield)

This sounds like what I need (https://github.com/billroy/socket.io-arduino-client) but I can't get it to work and I can't find any other documentation on the web as well.

- The 'how to' section in the README file doesn't use SocketIO but just WebSockets
- If I use the 'Hello' example from the lib, it sends 'hello world' successfully to the server, but there is no documentation about how it can listen to SocketIO events and how to emit SocketIO events.

This is what I have so far. Where am I wrong? Should I consider using something else or change my workflow? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Client reads from or writes to a buffer. Here they are continuously reading the buffer using socketIOclient.monitor(). So we can get the message there once an event is triggered

Comment: I can't see how this answer the question